# Upload video to youtube in java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, youtube-api

I have a video in my local disk i want to upload it on youtube through my application. Can you give me the guidelines to follow the same. please gve me steps to perform that or code or links.
Thanks in advance.

After the solution suggested i tried with:
gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/users/uploads (with users as some username) but i am getting IOException.i.e There was a problem communicating with the service.

```
  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:641)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:589)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1319)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:490)
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:470)
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:534)
        at com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.insert(MediaService.java:353)
        at ytupload.YouTubeWriteClient.uploadVideo(YouTubeWriteClient.java:508)
        at ytupload.YouTubeWriteClient.main(YouTubeWriteClient.java:828)
```

Plz help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

did you check the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java) on google developers guide, check the [Video Upload](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java#Uploading_Videos) section? you will find something like this:

```
VideoEntry newEntry = new VideoEntry();

YouTubeMediaGroup mg = newEntry.getOrCreateMediaGroup();
mg.setTitle(new MediaTitle());
mg.getTitle().setPlainTextContent("My Test Movie");
mg.addCategory(new MediaCategory(YouTubeNamespace.CATEGORY_SCHEME, "Autos"));
mg.setKeywords(new MediaKeywords());
mg.getKeywords().addKeyword("cars");
mg.getKeywords().addKeyword("funny");
mg.setDescription(new MediaDescription());
mg.getDescription().setPlainTextContent("My description");
mg.setPrivate(false);
mg.addCategory(new MediaCategory(YouTubeNamespace.DEVELOPER_TAG_SCHEME, "mydevtag"));
mg.addCategory(new MediaCategory(YouTubeNamespace.DEVELOPER_TAG_SCHEME, "anotherdevtag"));

newEntry.setGeoCoordinates(new GeoRssWhere(37.0,-122.0));
// alternatively, one could specify just a descriptive string
// newEntry.setLocation("Mountain View, CA");

MediaFileSource ms = new MediaFileSource(new File("file.mov"), "video/quicktime");
newEntry.setMediaSource(ms);

String uploadUrl =
  "http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads";

VideoEntry createdEntry = service.insert(new URL(uploadUrl), newEntry);
```

Probably you will the successfully authenticate before you can upload teh video like:

```
YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(clientID, developer_key);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: when i try to access this url http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads (with users as some username)it comes as NOT FOUND, but if i access http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/users/uploads (with users as some username) some xml gets displayed.. So i am confused which url to use. Suggestions please.

Comment: I have tried what u have told me...i have got some errors which i have posted above...please suggest something...

Comment: Did you install the Google Data Client Library? i didnt runt the code myself but it seems to be good documented on the site, what errors did you get?

Comment: Why dont you go through the document: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java#Getting_Started

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new `VideoEntry` object

The following code uploads the video:

```
VideoEntry newEntry = new VideoEntry();

YouTubeMediaGroup mg = newEntry.getOrCreateMediaGroup();
mg.setTitle(new MediaTitle());
mg.getTitle().setPlainTextContent("Title goes here");
mg.addCategory(new MediaCategory(YouTubeNamespace.CATEGORY_SCHEME, "Autos"));
mg.setKeywords(new MediaKeywords());
mg.getKeywords().addKeyword("keyword-here");
mg.setDescription(new MediaDescription());
mg.getDescription().setPlainTextContent("My description");
mg.setPrivate(false);
mg.addCategory(new MediaCategory(YouTubeNamespace.DEVELOPER_TAG_SCHEME, "mydevtag"));
mg.addCategory(new MediaCategory(YouTubeNamespace.DEVELOPER_TAG_SCHEME, "anotherdevtag"));

newEntry.setGeoCoordinates(new GeoRssWhere(37.0,-122.0));
// alternatively, one could specify just a descriptive string
// newEntry.setLocation("Mountain View, CA");

MediaFileSource ms = new MediaFileSource(new File("file.mov"), "video/quicktime");
newEntry.setMediaSource(ms);

String uploadUrl =
"http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads";

VideoEntry createdEntry = service.insert(new URL(uploadUrl), newEntry);
```

See https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java#Uploading_Videos